# loading jquery libraries dynamically only on certain aspx pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, jquery-ui

Due to a specific reason. I have my jquery references within the form tag which is within the body html tag instead of the head html tag.

Everything works fine till here but, due to how I am using my code , the jquery libraries are loaded on every 
page (aspx page).

I would like to load the jquery references on only the pages that need them. Is there a way I can do it ?

Here is my master page code currently :

```
<body>
    <form id="form2" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManagerService" runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ScriptMode="Auto" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js" ScriptMode="Auto" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js" ScriptMode="Auto" />
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
   </form>
</body>
```

Comment: If only specific pages need jQuery, it means that you are adding custom client side code on these pages. In this case, just load the jQuery references within your custom code, for example using a script tag.

Answer (score 0):

Remove in the masterpage the scriptreference to jQuery and add a ScriptManagerProxy with a reference to jQuery to the pages that need them:

> ```
> <body>
>     <form id="form2" runat="server">
>         <asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerService" runat="server">
>             <Scripts>
>                 <asp:ScriptReference Path="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ScriptMode="Auto" />
>                 <asp:ScriptReference Path="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js" ScriptMode="Auto" />
>                 <asp:ScriptReference Path="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js" ScriptMode="Auto" />
>             </Scripts>
>         </asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
>     </form>
> </body>
> ```